# How to avoid singularity in numerical integration in Python

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I am trying to compute the following integration in Python:

[image]

where the second term of the integrand is

[image]

I am currently computing it numerically by using Simpson's rule:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simps

r = np.linspace(rmin, rmax, 5000) 

f_val = some_complicated_function(r, params)

g_val = a*np.multiply(r**alpha, [math.exp(-b*r_) for r_ in r])

gamma = simps(np.multiply(f_val, g_val), r)
```

However, the result is not accurate for small `r` values. I checked the value of `g_val` and it was like below

```
array([2.48243025e-31, 1.62729999e-27, 3.31169129e-26, ...,
       1.34177288e-13, 1.34053922e-13, 1.33930643e-13])
```

which is probably causing the underflow.

The most typical workaround would be to integrate the function analytically rather than numerically. However, the problem is the function f(r) is very complicated and it is not available as an explicit (analytic) function.

Does anyone know any idea to compute this kind of integration more accurately?

Comment: Have you tried [`scipy.integrate.quad`](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html)?

Comment: Also, how do you know "the result is not accurate for small r values"? (I'm not doubting you--I'm just not sure how you know this.  You show some small values for `g_val`, but we have no way to judge the accuracy of those numbers.)

Comment: Yes, I tried `scipy.integrate.quad` but my computation became very slow (Spyder even froze)

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is no way to judge the "accuracy" in general. However, what I am doing here is to reproduce a result from a paper, so I can evaluate the "accuracy" by comparing my results with that of the paper.